# Stop Visual Studio 2022 process from command line

Tags: windows, visual-studio, powershell

Is there a way to use `Stop-Process` in PowerShell to close Visual Studio 2022?

Task Manager shows the following for an instance of Visual Studio:

[image]

It isn't clear which process I should call `Stop-Process` on to gracefully exit the program.

Comment: Just wanted to add, that if you were to right-click on the Visual Studio Process (not the group of them, but the first item after expanding the group), you can click on **Go to details**. This would have taken you to the **Details** tab and highlighted the exact process name you'd need to pass to `Stop-Process`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
get-process devenv | kill
```

Should do the trick

Comment: Thank you! Looks like this also works: `Stop-Process -Name devenv`.